# How to plot 3D matrix CSV data in Gnuplot with splot using the first row and column as the x y coordinates?

Tags: csv, gnuplot

How can I plot (a 3D plot) a matrix in Gnuplot having such data structure. I cannot find a way to use the first row and column as a x and y ticks (or to ignore them)

```
,5,6,7,8
1,-6.20,-6.35,-6.59,-6.02
2,-6.39,-6.52,-6.31,-6.00
3,-6.36,-6.48,-6.15,-5.90
4,-5.79,-5.91,-5.87,-5.46
```

Is the `splot 'data.csv' matrix` the correct parameter to use ?

Comment: The docs appear to document using the first row/column as coordinates only for the `binary` format: http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/node330.html what a shame. Related examples at: http://www.gnuplot.info/demo_5.3/image2.html I'll just stick to explicit coordinates `x0 y0 z00 \n x0 y1 z01` for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give using a format specification; here we need to tell the seperator ','. The following works for me:

```
splot 'data.csv' using 1:2:3 '%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf' with linespoints pt 6 ps 2 lw 3
```

except that the first line is ignored, which is probably right?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But if you look at the Y scale - it's not showing the correct values (which should be 5,6,7,8). X scale is OK 1,2,3,4. The Z scale shows values from the row that starts with "2". Btw. I am using Gnuplot 4.4.

Comment: This pretty much do what I sort of need: splot 'data.csv' using 0:0:2 '%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf' with linespoints pt 6 ps 2 lw 3
Now I'd like to plot more of such plots like the "fence plot" in the examples.. But that's a different story.

Comment: Sorry for bringing up this really old thread. I have data that looks exactly like the one posted (even same number of lines & columns). When I try your answer, I only get `Formatted input can only handle 7 data columns`. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Indeed. The splot parameters that I used that time, no longer works for Gnuplot 5.0. I quickly checked 4.4, and the command posted here works OK. I suppose this could be a bug in 5.0. I raised a ticket: https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1675/

Comment: @JuliusNaeumann The bug has been fixed, but I am not sure how it will take until next Gnuplot release: https://github.com/gnuplot/gnuplot/commit/cdeb4276760beb654b52063daf450342bd08caa4